# JSON compatibility with Mapbox Studio

Tags: python, json, format, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to use a [JSON file](https://filebin.net/ebx2qdvha5la8i4c) in Mapbox studio for network analysis but it gives me an error:

> Input failed. "type" member required on line 1.

The representative sample of JSON file is:

```
"version": 0.6,
    "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.56.2 b688b00f",
    "osm3s": {
        "timestamp_osm_base": "2020-03-27T11:58:01Z",
        "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
    },
    "elements": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "id": 123458059,
            "lat": -38.3344495,
            "lon": 143.5394486
        },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "id": 123458066,
            "lat": -38.3394461,
            "lon": 143.5923655,
            "tags": {
                "crossing": "traffic_signals",
                "highway": "traffic_signals"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "way",
            "id": 769574290,
            "nodes": [
                7183581936,
                681081177,
                1561328098,
                1539139562,
                448021781
            ],
            "tags": {
                "highway": "trunk",
                "lanes": "2",
                "maxspeed": "80",
                "name": "Princes Highway",
                "ref": "A1",
                "source:maxspeed:sign": "mapillary"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "way",
            "id": 776227225,
            "nodes": [
                1017428185,
                317738200
            ],
            "tags": {
                "alt_name": "Princes Highway",
                "highway": "trunk",
                "lanes": "2",
                "maxspeed": "50",
                "name": "Murray Street",
                "ref": "A1",
                "source:maxspeed:sign": "OpenStreetCam",
                "source:name": "services.land.vic.gov.au"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Does the error occur because of the specification of the format? Do we need to reformat the features or types?

Comment: What does "load into Mapbox Studio" mean, exactly? The error suggests that it might be looking for the last element in your `elements` list, only: it contains a `type` key.

Comment: ...but _what does it expect the JSON to **contain**_? The error says it's expecting a `type` member, and an object nested inside your payload _contains_ a `type` member.

Answer (score 2):

To [upload data to Mapbox](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/uploads/) you will need to convert your JSON file to [GeoJSON](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/geojson/), a [subset](https://geojson.org/) of the JSON format. For example:

```
{"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -76.9750541388,
                38.8410857803
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Southern Ave",
            "marker-symbol": "rail-metro",
            "title": "Southern Ave",
            "url": "http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/pids/showpid.cfm?station_id=107",
            "lines": [
                "Green"
            ],
            "address": "1411 Southern Avenue, Temple Hills, MD 20748"
        }
    },
    {
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -76.935256783,
                38.9081784965
            ]
        },
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
            "description": "Deanwood",
            "marker-symbol": "rail-metro",
            "title": "Deanwood",
            "url": "http://www.wmata.com/rider_tools/pids/showpid.cfm?station_id=65",
            "lines": [
                "Orange"
            ],
            "address": "4720 Minnesota Avenue NE, Washington, DC 20019"
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: The size of JSON file is large. It would be really hard for me to manually convert all features to GeoJSON file. Is there a way / coverter that will automatially convert JSON to GEoJSON? My file is here:https://filebin.net/ebx2qdvha5la8i4c/json.json?t=1quwtify

Comment: @CaseMsee - it looks like you are using the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). You should therefore be able to export elements [as a GeoJSON](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_turbo/GeoJSON) directly.

Answer (score 0):

Mapbox accepts GeoJSON, you'll need to ask Overpass to return data as GeoJSON.